Quantile to Quantile function when two random variables are linearly related
Assume we have $F_X$ and $F_Y$ as cumulative distribution functions of the two variables $X$ and $Y$, and $F^{-1}_X$, $F^{-1}_Y$ are the inverse of them. I am trying to show the following:  We take an $x \sim X$ value and calculate the probability of $X$ being at most as large as this value: $P(X \leq x)=F_X(x)=p$. Then we need to find the corresponding $y$ value, for which $P(Y \leq y)=p=F_X(x)$. We can represent the function from $x$ to $y$ as $y=F^{-1}_Y(F_X(x))$.
Now, also we assume that we know there is a linear relationship between two variables, $Y=aX+b$. I want to show that $F^{-1}_Y(F_X(x))$ in this case outputs $ax+b$. For that, I wanted to explicitly show $y$ in terms of $x$ when we have $y=ax+b$. Since $P(X \leq x)=P(Y \leq y)$, we have:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_X(t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^{y}f_Y(t)dt$$
Due to the linear relationship $y=ax+b$, we also have $f_Y(y)=f_X(\dfrac{y-b}{a})\dfrac{1}{|a|}$ due to transformation of random variables. After that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_X(t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^{y}f_X(\dfrac{t-b}{a})\dfrac{1}{|a|}dt$$ At this point, I became stuck. I wanted to obtain the same integrand and from there simply equate $x$ with the upper limit of the integral on the right, but from here I am not able to see a way forward. How can one proceed from here?

More simply :
$$
F_X(x) = F_Y(y) = \Bbb{P}(Y \le y) = \Bbb{P}(aX+b \le y) = \Bbb{P}\left(X \le \frac{y-b}{a}\right) = F_X\left(\frac{y-b}{a}\right),
$$
hence $y = ax+b$.

How was it possible to go from $\Bbb{P}(aX+b \le y)$ to $\Bbb{P}\left(X \le \frac{y-b}{a}\right)$?

@UfukCanBicici. The two inequalities are equivalent ans thus these events are associated to the same probability.

One more question, this is only valid when $a > 0$, is that right?

@UfukCanBicici. $a$ cannot be negative, because the relation $F_X(x) = F_Y(y)$ implies $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{f_X(x)}{f_Y(y)} \ge 0$ by differentiation. If $Y = aX+b$ with $a$ negative, then the relation $F_X(x) = F_Y(y)$ cannot be satisfied, because it would require that one of the two cumulative functions is decreasing.
